# Bot Framework v3 SSO with Teams

Tags: c#, oauth, botframework, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

I am building a chatbot for Teams where the bot needs to connect to graph on behalf of the user. I'm working in C# with BotFramework v3 (for business reasons I cannot move to v4), my BotBuilder package is on version 3.20.1.

**The problem:** On Webchat, no problem, the bot displays the sign in card, I get redirected to a login page. When logged in, I get the magic number, which I paste into my bot and everything is fine.

On Teams, however, I click on the button, get directed to the login page and once logged in, the tab closes, no magic number and the channel doesn't get anything.

**Here is what is configured:**

1. Permissions:
   [image]
2. The AAD v2 connection to my Azure app:

[image]

3. My valid domains in the teams manifest:
   [image]

I've also changed my sign in button to an open url button when in Teams channel as it is a problem mentioned here https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/2104 (and indeed sign in button doesn't react).

**The code:**

```cs
public override async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
   var token = await context.GetUserTokenAsync(ConnectionName).ConfigureAwait(false);
   var oauthToken = context.Activity.ChannelData.oauthToken?.Value as string;
   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oauthToken))
      await DoThingsWithToken(context, oauthToken);
   else
   context.Call(await CreateGetTokenDialog(context), DoThingsWithToken);
}
```

```cs
private async Task<GetTokenDialog> CreateGetTokenDialog(IDialogContext context)
{
   return new GetTokenDialog(
      ConnectionName,
      $"Please sign in to {ConnectionName} to proceed.",
      "Sign In",
      2,
      "Hmm. Something went wrong, let's try again.");
}
```

```cs
private async Task DoThingsWithToken(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<GetTokenResponse> tokenResponse)
{
   var token = (await tokenResponse).Token;
   // Do stuff...
}
```

I've looked online, but couldn't find any doc for SDK v3 anymore, nor people having this exact issue. Could anyone point me if it's a config problem, SDK version problem, or something else? And how to fix it?

[Edit] The documentation followed to configure the Teams SSO: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-bots-with-sso

Thank you, Best regards.

Comment: Are you getting some error or logs when doing so? Have you tried the same thing on Teams web browser?

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Comment: Hi, so same behavior is happening from the web browser and the app and we don't have any error... in fact we don't have anything, it's like nothing is happening once we log in... I really don't get it

Comment: I tried but unable to repro it. I will check more and update you if I find anything

Comment: Are you following any sample or documentation? if yes, could you share so that we can try it with our end.

Comment: Hi @HunaidHanfee-MSFT unfortunately my colleague is the one who did the set up for this part, and he is on holiday and didn't give me the links he followed (I know there were multiple). I will come back to you after the weekend with the documentation so I can be accurate in the info I'm sharing :-) Thank you for helping us!

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT so my colleague told me the link he used is this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-bots-with-sso I'll also update the question to include it :)

Comment: I setup the app following docs and tested it on Teams Desktop client. It works fine. Didn't face any issue and get the message showing my name and image after signing in.

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Comment: So we made progress on this issue, it is still not working. We know for sure that the login is working in webchat without magic number now but still in Teams it seems like either the channel doesn't get the token or doesn't submit it to the bot (we have no hit in message controller nor dialog when remote debugging)

Comment: Can you please check if the configuration is correct? You are using sample mention in the doc you shared as it is? or made changes? For me it is working without doing changes.